# bash 2.0 string matching

Tags: regex, bash

I'm on GNU bash, version **2.05**b.0(1)-release (2002). I'd like to determine whether the value of `$1` is a path in one of those `/path/*.log` rules in, say, `/etc/logrotate.conf`. It's not my box so I can't upgrade it.

Edit: my real goal is given `/path/actual.log` answer whether it is already governed by logrotate or if all the current rules miss it. I wonder then if my script should just run `logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf` and see if `/path/actual.log` is in the output. This seems simpler and covers all the cases as opposed to this other approach.

*But I still want to know how to approach string matching in Bash 2.0 in general...*

- the line itself can start with some white space or none
- it's not a match if it is in a commented line (comments are lines where the first non white space char is `#`)
- there can be one or more paths on the same line to the left of `$1`

  - like if `$1` is `/my/path/*.log` and the line in question is

    - `/other/path*.log /yet/another.log /my/path/*.log {`
- there can be one or more paths to the right as well
- the line itself can end with `{` and even more white space or not
- paths can be contained in double-quotes or not
- it can be assumed that the file is a valid logrotate conf file.

I have something that seems to work in Bash 4 but not in Bash 2.05. Where can I go to read what Bash 2.0 supports? How would this matching be checked in Bash 2.0?

Comment: You might post your Bash 4 code so we can see what post-2.0 features you are using. You can also consult the [`bash` release notes](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS), which go back to "what's new since `bash` 1.14.7".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a terse `bash` changelog [here](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS).

You'll see that `=~`, the regex-matching operator, didn't get introduced until version 3.0.

Thus, your best bet is to use a *utility* to perform the regex matching for you; e.g.:

```
if grep -Eq '<your-extended-regex>' <<<"$1"; then ...
```

---

`grep -Eq '<your-extended-regex>' <<<"$1"`:

- **IS** like `[[ $1 =~ <your-extended-regex> ]]` in Bash 3.0+ in that **its exit code indicates whether the literal value of `$1` matches the extended regex `<your-extended-regex>`**

  - Note that Bash 3.1 changed the interpretation of the RHS to treat quoted (sub)strings as *literals*.
  - Also note that `grep -E` may support a slightly different regular-expression dialect.
- **is NOT** like it in that the `grep` solution **cannot return capture groups**; by contrast, Bash 3.0+ provides the overall match and capture groups via special array variable `${BASH_REMATCH[@]}`.

Comment: was `egrep` deprecated at some point in favor of `grep -e`? The script has to run in Bash 2 through current Bash....

Comment: `grep -E`, not `grep -e` or `egrep`, was always the POSIX way to enable ERE; `egrep` is just a handy convenience extension added by GNU.

Comment: ...and your version of `grep` is very much separate from your version of bash; grep will behave the same way no matter which shell invokes it (or if it's run without any shell at all).

Comment: @user1011471: Charles is right - updated; as for `egrep`: the POSIX spec states, "The old egrep and fgrep commands are likely to be supported for many years to come as implementation extensions, allowing historical applications to operate unmodified."